# I2C SCL line stays low

Tags: c, clock, i2c, pic, lcd

I am trying to develop code for establishing I2C communication between PIC32MK1024MCM064 and I2C 16x2 LCD screen (via PCF8574 I2C expander). For now I am just trying to send any letter to get depicted on the LCD and verify it is working, and I got this problem with I2C line idling low. I made sure my hardware is all right: 5.1k pull ups on +3.3V logic lines, +5V LCD supply, 100 kHz I2C speed, a lot of bypass capacitors where needed, wiring is right. All this is verified.

So I am getting the acknowledgement bits from the LCD, so there is the response between the MCU and LCD, but other than that I dont know what to look for. I read that there can be similar problems related to clock stretching, but this is not the case because I have only one slave and one master device on the bus, thus clock stretching is disabled in the software. I really appreciate any help.

PIC32MK1024MCM064 code:

```
// DEVCFG3
#pragma config USERID = 0xFFFF          // Enter Hexadecimal value (Enter Hexadecimal value)
#pragma config PWMLOCK = OFF            // PWM IOxCON lock (PWM IOxCON register writes accesses are not locked or protected)
#pragma config FUSBIDIO2 = ON           // USB2 USBID Selection (USBID pin is controlled by the USB2 module)
#pragma config FVBUSIO2 = ON            // USB2 VBUSON Selection bit (VBUSON pin is controlled by the USB2 module)
#pragma config PGL1WAY = OFF            // Permission Group Lock One Way Configuration bit (Allow multiple reconfigurations)
#pragma config PMDL1WAY = OFF           // Peripheral Module Disable Configuration (Allow multiple reconfigurations)
#pragma config IOL1WAY = OFF            // Peripheral Pin Select Configuration (Allow multiple reconfigurations)
#pragma config FUSBIDIO1 = ON           // USB1 USBID Selection (USBID pin is controlled by the USB1 module)
#pragma config FVBUSIO1 = ON            // USB2 VBUSON Selection bit (VBUSON pin is controlled by the USB1 module)
// DEVCFG2
#pragma config FPLLIDIV = DIV_1         // System PLL Input Divider (1x Divider)
#pragma config FPLLRNG = RANGE_BYPASS   // System PLL Input Range (Bypass)
#pragma config FPLLICLK = PLL_FRC     // System PLL Input Clock Selection (FRC is input to the System PLL)
#pragma config FPLLMULT = MUL_2         // System PLL Multiplier (PLL Multiply by 1)
#pragma config FPLLODIV = DIV_2        // System PLL Output Clock Divider (2x Divider)
#pragma config BORSEL = HIGH            // Brown-out trip voltage (BOR trip voltage 2.1v (Non-OPAMP deviced operation))
#pragma config UPLLEN = OFF             // USB PLL Enable (USB PLL Disabled)
// DEVCFG1
#pragma config FNOSC = FRC              // Oscillator Selection Bits (Internal Fast RC (FRC))
#pragma config DMTINTV = WIN_0          // DMT Count Window Interval (Window/Interval value is zero)
#pragma config FSOSCEN = OFF            // Secondary Oscillator Enable (Disable Secondary Oscillator)
#pragma config IESO = OFF               // Internal/External Switch Over (Disabled)
#pragma config POSCMOD = OFF            // Primary Oscillator Configuration (Primary osc disabled)
#pragma config OSCIOFNC = OFF           // CLKO Output Signal Active on the OSCO Pin (Disabled)
#pragma config FCKSM = CSDCMD           // Clock Switching and Monitor Selection (Clock Switch Disabled, FSCM Disabled)
#pragma config WDTPS = PS1              // Watchdog Timer Postscaler (1:1)
#pragma config WDTSPGM = STOP           // Watchdog Timer Stop During Flash Programming (WDT stops during Flash programming)
#pragma config WINDIS = NORMAL          // Watchdog Timer Window Mode (Watchdog Timer is in non-Window mode)
#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF             // Watchdog Timer Enable (WDT Disabled)
#pragma config FWDTWINSZ = WINSZ_25     // Watchdog Timer Window Size (Window size is 25%)
#pragma config DMTCNT = DMT31           // Deadman Timer Count Selection (2^31 (2147483648))
#pragma config FDMTEN = OFF             // Deadman Timer Enable (Deadman Timer is disabled)
// DEVCFG0
#pragma config DEBUG = OFF              // Background Debugger Enable (Debugger is disabled)
#pragma config JTAGEN = OFF             // JTAG Enable (JTAG Disabled)
#pragma config ICESEL = ICS_PGx3        // ICE/ICD Comm Channel Select (Communicate on PGEC3/PGED3)
#pragma config TRCEN = OFF              // Trace Enable (Trace features in the CPU are disabled)
#pragma config BOOTISA = MIPS32         // Boot ISA Selection (Boot code and Exception code is MIPS32)
#pragma config FECCCON = ECC_DECC_DISABLE_ECCON_WRITABLE// Dynamic Flash ECC Configuration Bits (ECC and Dynamic ECC are disabled (ECCCON<1:0> bits are writable))
#pragma config FSLEEP = OFF             // Flash Sleep Mode (Flash is powered down when the device is in Sleep mode)
#pragma config DBGPER = PG_ALL          // Debug Mode CPU Access Permission (Allow CPU access to all permission regions)
#pragma config SMCLR = MCLR_NORM        // Soft Master Clear Enable (MCLR pin generates a normal system Reset)
#pragma config SOSCGAIN = G3            // Secondary Oscillator Gain Control bits (Gain is G3)
#pragma config SOSCBOOST = ON           // Secondary Oscillator Boost Kick Start Enable bit (Boost the kick start of the oscillator)
#pragma config POSCGAIN = G3            // Primary Oscillator Coarse Gain Control bits (Gain Level 3 (highest))
#pragma config POSCBOOST = ON           // Primary Oscillator Boost Kick Start Enable bit (Boost the kick start of the oscillator)
#pragma config POSCFGAIN = G3           // Primary Oscillator Fine Gain Control bits (Gain is G3)
#pragma config POSCAGCDLY = AGCRNG_x_25ms// AGC Gain Search Step Settling Time Control (Settling time = 25ms x AGCRNG)
#pragma config POSCAGCRNG = ONE_X       // AGC Lock Range bit (Range 1x)
#pragma config POSCAGC = Automatic      // Primary Oscillator Gain Control bit (Automatic Gain Control for Oscillator)
#pragma config EJTAGBEN = NORMAL        // EJTAG Boot Enable (Normal EJTAG functionality)
// DEVCP
#pragma config CP = OFF                 // Code Protect (Protection Disabled)
// SEQ
#pragma config TSEQ = 0x0               // Boot Flash True Sequence Number (Enter Hexadecimal value)
#pragma config CSEQ = 0xFFFF            // Boot Flash Complement Sequence Number (Enter Hexadecimal value)
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <xc.h>                         
#include <toolchain_specifics.h>        
#include <stddef.h>                    
#include <stdint.h>                    
#include <stdbool.h>                    
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include "stdio.h" 
#include <sys/attribs.h>  
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define CPU_CLOCK_FREQUENCY 8000000
#define _CP0_GET_COUNT()  _mfc0 (_CP0_COUNT, _CP0_COUNT_SELECT)
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//#define MASTER_WRITE_LCD_RED  (0x7C)     //  7 BITS ONLY Address of 0x7C Last bit is R/W (1 for reading, and 0 for writing)
#define MASTER_WRITE_LCD_BLUE (0B1000000)     //  7 BITS ONLY Address of 0x20 Last bit is R/W (1 for reading, and 0 for writing)
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void delay_ms ( uint32_t delay_ms)
{
    uint32_t startCount, endCount;

    endCount=((CPU_CLOCK_FREQUENCY/1000)*delay_ms)/2;

    startCount=_CP0_GET_COUNT();
    while((_CP0_GET_COUNT()-startCount)<endCount);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void I2C__initialization(void){
    
    //The datasheet declares that when the I2C module is enabled pins are assigned automatically 
    //(For I2C module nr.1 SCL is pin 5 and SDA is pin 6 ) and TRIS bits are overriden anyway.
    //I believe there is nothing else to do with I2C pin setup other than enabling the I2C module
    
    //PIC is operating in master mode, so address and address mask register are irrelevant for this application.
    
    //PB2CLK is same as SYSCLK here (8Mhz)
    
    ANSELG = 0xFFFFFE7F;          //Enable digital inputs for I2C pins (Clear ANSEL RG7 and RG8)        
    
    I2C1BRG = 0x00000010;         //Baud rate setup register (Here 50 kHz for the 100kb/s data rate)
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    I2C1CON = 0x00000000;         //Resetting register to clear all bits (to ensure right setup)  
    I2C1CONbits.SDAHT = 0b1;      //Minimum of 300 ns hold time on SDA after the falling edge of SCL
    I2C1CONbits.SIDL = 0b1;       //Discontinue module operation when device enters Idle mode
    I2C1CONbits.SCLREL = 0b1;     //Release SCL clock
    I2C1CONbits.STREN = 0b0;      //Disable software or receive clock stretching
    I2C1CONbits.DISSLW = 0b1;     //Slew rate control is disabled
    I2C1CONbits.SMEN = 0b0;       //Disable SMBus input thresholds
    I2C1CONbits.ON = 0b1;         //Enable I2C module
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void I2C__state(void){
    while( (I2C1CON & 0x0000001F) || (I2C1STAT & 0x00000004) );  //Checking is the I2C bus is idle, waiting until it becomes idle (checking all I2C status bits)
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void I2C__Start(void){
    I2C__state();
    I2C1CONbits.SEN = 0b1;     //Initiate Start condition on SDAx and SCLx pins
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void I2C__Stop(void){
    I2C__state();
    I2C1CONbits.PEN = 0b1;    //Initiate Stop condition on SDAx and SCLx pins
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void I2C_Repeated_Start(void){
    I2C__state();
    I2C1CONbits.RSEN = 0b1;   //Initiate Repeated Start condition on SDAx and SCLx pins
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void I2C__Write(uint8_t I2C_data){
    I2C__state();
    while(I2C1STATbits.TBF != 0);        //Ensuring the transmit buffer is completely empty before the new transmission
    while(I2C1STATbits.TRSTAT != 0);     //Ensuring the transmission has ended
    I2C1TRN = I2C_data;                  //Loading the data to the I2C transmit buffer for transmission
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
uint8_t I2C__Read (uint8_t ACK){
   uint8_t data = 0;
   I2C__state();
   I2C1CONbits.RCEN = 0b1;            //Enables Receive mode for I2C
   while(I2C1STATbits.RBF != 0);      //Ensuring the receive buffer is completely empty before new reception
   data = (I2C1RCV & 0x000000FF);     //Extracting lower 8 bits of the I2C data from a 32 bit I2C receive register
   I2C1CONbits.ACKEN = ACK;
   return data;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main ( void )
{ 
    TRISAbits.TRISA7 = 1;    //Button input setup
    
    TRISGbits.TRISG9 = 1;    //Button input setup
    
    ANSELA = 0x00000000;     //Enable PORT A digital inputs (VERY IMPORTANT) 
    
    ANSELG = 0x00000000;     //Enable PORT A digital inputs (VERY IMPORTANT) 
    
    TRISBbits.TRISB14 = 0; 
    LATBbits.LATB14 = 0;     //LED 1
    
    TRISBbits.TRISB15 = 0; 
    LATBbits.LATB15 = 0;     //LED 2
    
    TRISGbits.TRISG6 = 0;
    LATGbits.LATG6 = 0;      //LED 3
    
    I2C__initialization();
     
    while (1)
    {       
        //Background blinking leds
        
        LATBbits.LATB14 = 1;
        delay_ms(200);
        LATBbits.LATB14 = 0;
        LATBbits.LATB15 = 1;
        delay_ms(200);
        LATBbits.LATB15 = 0;
        
        if(!PORTAbits.RA7){    //Button press initiates I2C event
            LATGbits.LATG6 = 1; 
            I2C__Start();
            I2C__Write(MASTER_WRITE_LCD_BLUE);
            I2C__Write(0x58);                 //This should display letter ,,b" according to the LCD symbol table, any letter in general just to see it working
            I2C__Stop();
            delay_ms(200);
            LATGbits.LATG6 = 0; 
        }
            
    } 
    return (EXIT_FAILURE); 
}
```

[image]

Comment: shouldn't the clock init high?

Comment: Check who holds SCL low, master or slave? Does CPU wait in infinite loop in `I2C__state()` after `I2C__Write()`?

Comment: @dimich What is method to check who is pulling the clock low? How can I check that?

Comment: @ViliusŽalėnas Detach SCL line e.g. from slave. If it become high on master's side, it means slave pulls it down.

Comment: @dimich But if I run I2C packet on an empty line which is driven only by master, I wont get acknowledgement. So if master is not pulling the SCL low, I should see only the I2C address section surrounded by logic high level from both sides? Is that right?

Comment: @ViliusŽalėnas I mean detach and measure it after bytes are sent, "in vivo". Also for debug i'd check what is CPU doing after bytes are sent. Is it in busy loop somewhere? If hardware debugger is not available, debug output to serial port may help.

Comment: @dimich So I found out that the SCL is idling high after the POR but after first data packet it becomes low (but while SCL is idling low the program does not jam, I can still send I2C packets even getting ACKS from the LCD, the background code also runs perfect) So you guess that my MCU hangs somewhere after write operations??

Comment: @ViliusŽalėnas I don't know does it hang or not, so i suggested to check it. If commands are sent and acknowledged, what is actual observed problem? No output on display? Maybe I2C communication is ok but display initialization sequence is wrong? Usually LCD controllers require some initialization sequence to turn display on, configure internal charge pump etc.

Comment: To check who is pulling line low you can use two pull-ups (on the master and slave side) and series resistor 100  Ohm in SCK line between them. Voltage drop on the resistor will be about 60 mV on your conditions, and the lower side of the resistor will point to the source.

Comment: The line I2C_SCL and I2C_Data should be switched to high impedance with the `TRIS` register. Have you done this?